# What is the error in the following chunk of code in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am a newbie to Swift programming language and i found a code project from
[GITHUB PROJECT](https://github.com/jquave/Swift-Tutorial/tree/Part2)

It has got a following error as shown in the image below. Please help me to sort it out
[image]

Comment: Error states what is the problem. You need to put { after that if let statement.

Comment: i tried but no success

Comment: Your code works completely fine for me

Comment: @MidhunMP: You can have multiple optional bindings within a single if-statement, they are separated by commas.

Comment: Check for invisible characters (Editor -> Show Invisibles ...) – And please copy/paste your *code*, not screenshots!

Comment: I can confirm @EICaptain: That method (downloaded from the GitHub repository) compiles without problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91548/discussion-between-ei-captain-and-martin-r).

Comment: @DaniellaD'Cruz: OK, that clears it up. Xcode 6.1 is **old**. The current version is Xcode 7 (Swift 2). You need as least Xcode 6.4 (Swift 1.2) for if-statements with multiple optional bindings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the line of the error to

```
if let rowData: NSDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as? Dictionary{
```

You will notice i changed the comma "," with a opening curly bracket "{".

This is because in Swift whenever we write an if statement we need to encapsulate our code we want to run in curly brackets.

see this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html) for more info.

Thanks

**EDIT:** As @Martin pointed out

> You can have multiple optional bindings within a single if-statement, they are separated by commas.

So my origional answer is now void. But I will leave it here to help inform people like myself.

Thanks again.

Comment: You can have multiple optional bindings within a single if-statement, they are separated by commas.

Comment: So – in a sense – you were right: OP is using an old Xcode version which does not support this language feature.